# Force a reload of Listbox items(usercontrols) on ListBox Visibility Changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox that is bound to a List of UserControls.

The uc has a TextBlock that has an animation that fires OnLoad.

```
 <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.8"      Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="16" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style
```

Works fine. My problem is the List can be Collapsed by the user. When the user unCollapses the List I need the aanimation to fire again (it doesn't, of course -  because they are already loaded). Doesn't seem to be any other event that would work. Soo..I'm trying to dump the ItemSource and reload them. It won't hurt as there are only up to 10 or 12 items. I have an ICommand in the ViewModel that catches the Visibility Collapse...but I'm stuck there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is copying the Collection on Collapse...then Clearing. Now I reload the copy when Visibility becomes Visible. Thanks